# Index Error: list index out of range in "for i in range(len(x)):"

Tags: python, list

```
    direc = "emails/"
      files = os.listdir(direc)

      emails = [direc + email for email in files]
      words = []
      c = len (emails)
      for email in emails:
        f = open(email)
        blob = f.read()
        words += blob.split( )
        print c
        c-=1

      for i in range(len(words)):
        words [i] = words[i].lower()

dictionary = Counter(words)

  print dictionary.most_common(5000)
```

This code works fine if the emails are short, when the emails exceed 10 words, give the error: "list index out of range" in line words [i] = words[i].lower()

Comment: Fix your indentation. Not really sure on whats going on here but have you tried appending/extending to the list instead of ```+= blob.split()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    words [i] = words[i].lower()
```

Can be rewritten as

```
words = map(str.lower, words)
```

It's nearly always a code-smell to iterate over a list by index `for i in range(len(x))`, if you need the index you should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: It works. How can I do with: `words [i] = words[i].translate(None, string.punctuation
    if(words[i].isdigit()):
      words[i]='number'.` I'm begginer. 
Thank you very much